# wanted the cursor to jump to other field

Tags: iphone, ipad, uitextfield

hii guys, i am working on a crossword application.I took UITextField to the respective cell to enable user to enter his word, and also implemented the code which moves the cursor to the adjacent field if a textField is available in both horizontal and across . i made sure that each textField can accept only single character.

my requirement :
-if i am filling a vertical word the  cursor should move to the next vertical word and if no vertical field is available should jump to first horizontal word

-if i am filling a horizontal word the cursor should move to the next horizontal word nd if no horizontal field is available should jump to first vertical word

```
-(IBAction)textFieldEditingChanged:(CrossWordTextField*)textField{
int difference;
if ([textField.text length]==1) {
    //[textField resignFirstResponder];
    difference=13;
    if (horizontalDirection) {
        difference=1;
    }
}
else if([textField.text length]==0){
    [textField resignFirstResponder];
    difference=-13;
    if (horizontalDirection) {
        difference=-1;
    }
}

for (UIView *cellView in crossWordView.subviews) {
    if (cellView.tag==textField.superview.tag+difference) {
        for (CrossWordTextField *nextTf in cellView.subviews) {
            if ([nextTf isKindOfClass:[CrossWordTextField class]]) {
                [nextTf becomeFirstResponder];
            }
        }
    }
}
```

}

i placed a view and placed a UITextField on the view for each and every cell.
crossWordTextField is a class which extend UITextField. i have taken this class so that i can use the properties of the textField.

plz help me in this regard. if needed much information plz revert i would provide the necessary information.

TNQ in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you have to work with a bidimensional matrix (array). It's hard to explain but I think the crossword as an square and its boundaries are such that your crossword fit within the matrix. So you will have some elements with text boxes and others with nothing (NULL). When you have the focus on a textbox you can query for neighbors text fields in that matrix. I have no enough time to write an example, but I hope this points you to a solution.